# Fancybox with "share" buttons linked to unique image

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fancybox, modal-dialog

I would like to display a facebook-like button within the Fancybox popup.

The interaction I'm imagining is similar to how Pinterest displays the social sharing buttons to the right of a modal popup (e.g. http://pinterest.com/pin/73465037641354472/). Each image has a unique url so that you can link to the content of the popup directly.

How can I:

1. Ensure that each image within my Fancybox gallery is attached to a unique URL
2. Display a Like button in the popup linked to that unique URL

For #1, I found the following code discussed in the following page: [this.id inside of fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813197/this-id-inside-of-fancybox)

```
$("a.fancybox").each(function() {
  var element = this;
  $(this).fancybox({
    'titleFormat'   : function() {
      var astring = '<span>' + element.id + '</span>';
      return astring;
     }
  });
});
```

Is this the code that I need? If so, what do I do in the HTML in order for this JavaScript to work properly?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Does each image in your gallery have it's own page?

Comment: No, they're all on a single page.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have a mechanism that based upon a unique URL to serve off the correct http://ogp.me og: meta tags to be parsed by Facebook's linter.

Remember the linter does not run javascript, so they will need to be correctly defined in the response stream.

**EDIT**

Example of each image having it's own URL.  These will aid in Facebook being able to get the correct html and og: tags.

```
http://example.com/images.php?id=1
http://example.com/images.php?id=2
http://example.com/images.php?id=3
```

Within the HTML response from each of those unique URLs, the correct og: tags are specified.  Within that HTML you should have a javascript redirect to the actual page to display the picture.  Since javascript wont be run by the linter, the linter should be able to read those og: tags.

See http://ogp.me for how to specify og tags.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand this answer. Can you please elaborate on the mechanism I should use?